# Division in pandas: multiple columns by another column of the same DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

There are several questions around this topic on SO, but none seem to raise the issue that I am having, I call:

```
df.div(df.col_name, axis = 'index')
```

on a dataframe which has 7 columns and 3596 rows, the result is invariably:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-5797510566fc> in <module>()

[.. several long calls...]

C:\Users\Ataturk\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.pyc in na_op(x, y)
    752             result = result.reshape(x.shape)
    753
--> 754         result = com._fill_zeros(result, x, y, name, fill_zeros)
    755
    756         return result

C:\Users\Ataturk\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.pyc in _fill_zeros(result, x, y, name, fill)
   1252                 signs = np.sign(result)
  1253                 nans = np.isnan(x.ravel())
-> 1254                 np.putmask(result, mask & ~nans, fill)
   1255
   1256                 # if we have a fill of inf, then sign it

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3596,) (25172,)
```

Division across specific columns works fine:

```
df.one_column / df.col_name
```

But as soon as I go to multiple columns, same error (with a different number in the last set of parentheses):

```
df[['one_column_name', 'another_column_name']] / df.col_name
```

I've tried the various possible syntaxes, `.div` and `/` and referencing through [] as well as `.name`, it's all the same. Dimensions fit, but it seems to append all the columns to be divided to each other, creating the second number, which is of course larger by a factor than the column that it then tries to divide by. What am I doing wrong?

df.info():

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 3596 entries, 0 to 3595
Data columns (total 7 columns):
bal_cast    3596 non-null int64
Degt        3596 non-null int64
Meln        3596 non-null int64
Levich      3596 non-null int64
Navu        3596 non-null int64
Mitr        3596 non-null int64
Sob         3596 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(7)
```

`bal_cast` is the name of the column I am trying to divide by; here is the exact division call, where the relevant dataframe is call `result`:

```
In [58]: result.div(result.bal_cast, axis='index')
```

Current conda install:

```
         platform : win-64
    conda version : 3.5.2
   python version : 2.7.6.final.0
```

Pandas: 0.14.0; Numpy: 1.8.1

EDIT: Following the discussion in the comments, smaller slices of the same table divide through without issue.

Comment: can you show ``df.info()`` your exact division call. and numpy/pandas versions, and platform.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, added all of the above into the question.

Comment: What is `result`? Same as `df`?

Comment: Yes, `result` is the name actually used in the code, I wrote `df` for the purposes of the question as more comprehensible.

Comment: I can reproduce this.  Something seems strange with `div`.

Comment: I can also reproduce it, but only with many rows. With 1000 rows it works, with 1500 not anymore.

Comment: @joris: I can break on a (3,2) frame.  `add`, `sub`, and `mul` all work, but `div` goes 'splodey.

Comment: prob ``com.fill_zeros`` is screwing up.... @DSM can you post an issue if you have a small example pls

Comment: @joris Same here, I took a 300-row slice from the table and it worked.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.  Opened [issue #7325](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7325) on github with my minimal failing case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workaround is this:

```
df.astype('float').div(df['column'].astype('float'),axis='index')
```

The filling algorithm is choking on this. If you are dividing integers by 0, then you get `inf`s. Their is a bug in that. See [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7325)

Casting to float 'solves' this problem as the a float / 0 is handled by numpy directly. Side note: the reasons pandas handles the division is because numpy int division is truncation and gives you back an integer (which is odd).

Integers give a weird/odd result in numpy.

```
In [10]: Series([1])/0
Out[10]: 
0    inf
dtype: float64

In [11]: Series([1]).values/0
Out[11]: array([0])
```

Floats are correct in numpy

```
In [12]: Series([1.])/0
Out[12]: 
0    inf
dtype: float64

In [14]: Series([1.]).values/0
Out[14]: array([ inf])
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Frankly, I'm just learning the language and its most prominent tools, so I can go ahead sticking to series which don't have zeroes in them, but it's good to have a workaround handy and maybe others will find this useful. I actually didn't expect this series to have zeroes.

Any idea why the error seems to reference incorrect dimensions? Does so quite consistently both in mine and DSM's cases. Or is it just reporting the dimensions of each series for information?

Comment: this is a bug, the error is a generic one; will be fixed for 0.14.1